# linux - pdf: How to change the width of multiple pages with different heights in pdf file

Tags: linux, pdf

I have pdf file with different page size (all the widths and heights are different)

I want to scale few of the pdf pages to same width which i will provide, keeping the page ratio (width/height) same.

How can i do this in linux - command line